# adb fails with "cannot bind 'local:5037'"

Tags: android

Any `adb` command results in the following output:

```
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
cannot bind 'local:5037'
ADB server didn't ACK
* failed to start daemon *
error: cannot connect to daemon
```

There is no running adb instance, and nothing is using TCP port 5037.

Comment: Check this answer maybe it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17638919/adb-not-running/37603398#37603398

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that the error says `local:5037`, not `tcp:5037`. ADB is actually trying to connect to an unix socket at `/tmp/5037`, which fails.

In my case this was because I ran adb as root before. Thus, the socket was owned by root, forbidding my user from removing it. Relevant excerpt from `strace adb fork-server server`:

```
socket(PF_LOCAL, SOCK_STREAM, 0)        = 8
unlink("/tmp/5037")                     = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
setsockopt(8, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, [1], 4) = 0
bind(8, {sa_family=AF_LOCAL, sun_path="/tmp/5037"}, 12) = -1 EADDRINUSE (Address already in use)
close(8)                                = 0
```

Comment: For anyone else who finds this, `sudo adb kill-server` may not free the port, and `sudo rm /tmp/5037` seems to fix it.